# 1:1 decoding of UTF-8 octets for visualization

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, utf-8

I'm making a tool (C#, WPF) for viewing binary data which may contain embedded text.  It's traditional for such data viewers to use two vertical columns, one displaying the hexadecimal value of each byte and the other displaying the ASCII character corresponding to each byte, if printable.

I've been thinking it would be nice to support display of embedded text using non-ASCII encodings as well, in particular UTF-8 and UTF-16.  The issue is that UTF code points don't map 1:1 with octets.  I would like to keep the output grid-aligned according to its location in the data, so I need every octet to map to *something* to appear in the corresponding cell in the grid.  What I'm thinking is that the end octet of each code point will map to the resulting Unicode character, and lead bytes map to placeholders that vary with sequence length (perhaps [circled forms](http://unicode-table.com/en/24F6/) and use color to distinguish them from the actual encoded characters), and continuation and invalid bytes similarly to placeholders.

```
struct UtfOctetVisualization
{
    enum Classification 
    { 
       Ascii, 
       NonAscii, 
       LeadByteOf2, 
       LeadByteOf3, 
       LeadByteOf4, 
       Continuation, 
       Error
    }

    Classification OctetClass;
    int CodePoint; // valid only when OctetClass == Ascii or NonAscii
}
```

The `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` method doesn't provide any information about the location each resulting character came from.

I could use `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()` and call [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6w985hz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passing a single byte at a time so that the `completed` output parameter gives a classification for each octet.

But in both methods, in order to have handling of invalid characters, I would need to implement a `DecoderFallback` class?  This looks complicated.

Is there a simple way to get this information using the APIs provided with .NET (in `System.Text` or otherwise)?  Using `System.Text.Decoder`, what would the fallback look like that fills in an output array shared with the decoder?

Or is it more feasible to write a custom UTF-8 recognizer (finite state machine)?

Comment: How are you going to distinguish random binary junk from genuine Unicode content? There's a lot of stuff that will seem legit, especially with UTF-16. And how are you going to distinguish other ambiguous ranges? For example, does `6f 6f` mean "oo" or "潯"?

Comment: @Jon: Visually, same way users do it with [the ASCII view in existing](http://www.digitalprank.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/um-hex-edit.png) [binary editor/viewers](http://www.sb-software.com/hexeditor/hexshot1.jpg).  The user will have to select the encoding for the right-hand pane.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason I read it as an attempt to detect and translate subranges of the input using perhaps different encodings for each range. Which is crazy. Single encoding will work with some help from the user. :-)

Comment: @Jon: If there are embedded strings using various encodings, might make sense to have multiple columns of text display, one with each encoding.  This question is about building the display using a prespecified decoding, not encoding detection (which is an interesting topic as well)

Comment: Yes, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

How about decoding one character at a time so that you can capture the number of bytes each character occupies. Something like this:

```
string data  = "hello????";

byte[] buffer = new byte[Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(data)];
int bufferIndex = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    int bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data, i, 1, buffer, bufferIndex);

    Console.WriteLine("Character: {0}, Position: {1}, Bytes: {2}", data[i], i, bytes);

    bufferIndex += bytes;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/poohHM

Those ???" in the string are supposed to be multi-byte characters, but SO dosent let me paste them in. See the Fiddle.

I dont this this is going to workout the way you want when you mix binary stuff with characters as @Jon has pointed out. I mean you'll see something, but it may not be what you expect, because the encoder wont be able to distinguish what bytes are supposed to be characters.

Comment: Oh, that is better, at least for real text data.  UTF formats are self-synchronizing so they deal with binary data pretty nicely.  The problem I see is when decoding of a multibyte character fails, finding which byte was bad (and what the prior bytes "should" have meant) will require extra work.

Comment: I mean, the idea is better.  Your answer and fiddle are encoding, not decoding.